# Get a single child note using lxml

Tags: python, lxml

**Edit -** The issue was that I was running an outdated version of lxml - I feel really stupid now but I'm glad I found out.

I'm having trouble iterating through an XML tree to export single child elements.

What I'm looking for is isolating child elements and exporting them in separate xml files. But my problem is that when I'm using the 'etree.iter' function, I'm not only getting the children elements, I'm also getting all following siblings. How can I only get one child element at the time?

This should explain it better. Here's my sample code:

```py
from lxml import etree

root = etree.XML("<users><user><name>Test</name><id>01</id></user> \
                         <user><name>Test</name><id>02</id></user> \
                         <user><name>Test</name><id>03</id></user></users>")

for record in root.iter("user"):
    print(etree.tostring(record))
```

It produces the following output

```
b'<user><name>Test</name><id>01</id></user><user><name>Test</name><id>02</id></user><user><name>Test</name><id>03</id></user></users>'
b'<user><name>Test</name><id>02</id></user><user><name>Test</name><id>03</id></user></users>'
b'<user><name>Test</name><id>03</id></user></users>'
```

But what I need is

```
b'<user><name>Test</name><id>01</id></user>'
b'<user><name>Test</name><id>02</id></user>'
b'<user><name>Test</name><id>03</id></user>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried using xpath but getting the same issue: `records = root.xpath('//user')` and then iterating through them with `for record in records:` but this produces the exact same result.

Comment: works fine for me (with version 4.6.4)

Comment: This was resolved after updating lxml to 4.6.4. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite not sure why `iter` is producing such an error. Try this, it works fine.

```
xn = etree.fromstring("<users><user><name>Test</name><id>01</id></user><user><name>Test</name><id>02</id></user><user><name>Test</name><id>03</id></user></users>")
user_nodes = xn.findall("user")
str_nodes = [etree.tostring(un) for un in user_nodes]
print(str_nodes)
```

produces an expected output

```
[
b'<user><name>Test</name><id>01</id></user>', 
b'<user><name>Test</name><id>02</id></user>', 
b'<user><name>Test</name><id>03</id></user>']
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried using this as well but it didn't work. I'm beginning to think something is wrong in how I'm set up, because when I run your exact code, I get `[b'<user><name>Test</name><id>01</id></user><user><name>Test</name><id>02</id></user><user><name>Test</name><id>03</id></user></users>', b'<user><name>Test</name><id>02</id></user><user><name>Test</name><id>03</id></user></users>', b'<user><name>Test</name><id>03</id></user></users>']` ! I'm using Jupyter Notebook with Python 3.9.7

Comment: lxml version is 4.6.3

Comment: This was tried on Py 3.8 / lxml - 3.6.4.

Comment: Indeed the issue was the version of lxml! I feel really stupid for not realizing this earlier. Thank you for your help!